# "java program 'no output' blank"

Tags: java

"Actually i was doing a problem from hackerEarth related to some arrangements i am noob right now so  i apologise for my bad code. Am getting blank output"
https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/arrays/1-d/practice-problems/algorithm/colourful-lights/

```
     import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Practise2{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = scan.nextInt();
        int m = scan.nextInt();
        int ArrForN[] = new int[n];
        int ArrForM[] = new int[m];
        int numb = 0 , pass = 1, store = 0 , val = 1 ;

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            ArrForN[i] = scan.nextInt();

        for(int j = 0; j < m ; m++)
            ArrForM[j] = j+1; 
        int y = 0;

        for(int x = 0 ; x < n ; x++){
              if(x < val*m) {    
                if(ArrForN[x] == 0){
                    ArrForN[x] = ArrForM[y];
                    numb++ ;
                    pass = pass* numb;
                    store = pass;
                    System.out.println(store);
                    y++ ;
                }
                else if(ArrForN[x] != 0)
                    y++ ;
              }
             else if(x == val*m){
               if(ArrForN[x] == 0){ 
                 System.out.println(store);  
                 val++ ;
                 numb = 0; 
                 pass = 0;
                 y = 0;    
                 ArrForN[x] = ArrForM[y];
                 numb++ ;
                 pass = pass* numb;
                 store = pass;
                 System.out.println(store); 
                 y++ ;
               }  
               else if(ArrForN[x] != 0)  
                   y++ ;

            }
        } 

    }
 }
```

P.S. I've already debugged it and nothing happened

Comment: debug it using the debugger

Comment: Try adding println statements into each case. There's several paths through this that could avoid printing anything

Comment: i added println statement nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

First, in this line:

```
for(int j = 0; j < m ; m++)
```

you must change `m` with `j`:

```
for(int j = 0; j < m ; j++)
```

As it is it leads to an infinite loop, I think it's obvious why.
Second, inside this loop:

```
for(int x = 0 ; x < n ; x++){
    .............
}
```

all your `System.out.println()` calls are included in 2 `if` statements:

```
if(ArrForN[x] == 0){
    ...........
}
```

which are never `true` if the user does not assign `0` to any of the array's `ArrForN` items when the program starts.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: @VaibhavBisht if this answered your question consider accepting it.